# Magento - Moving from Ip address to Domain Name

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am running magento 1.9.2.3 on my Linux server with Cpanel and I can access my Store via a dedicated IP address (E.X 259.259.259.259), Now I wish to point my server DNS to my domain name (www.example.com) so that I can access the store via domain name.

**My Question**: Since nothing is changing at the server side, will Magento works perfectly after moving to the domain name? Or there are some changes I am required to do?

Comment: for your security, don't share your ip address anymore.

Comment: Nowadays configuration option is in Stores >general>web>base urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you point your server with domain name after that

Login to admin panel:

Goto `System->Configuration->General->web->Unsecure` and change `Base URL` to your `domainname.com`

and Goto `System->Configuration->General->web->Secure` and change `Base URL` to your `domainname.com`

and clear your magento cache and if you are not able login via browser after chages then goto Cpanel `yourMagentoDir/var/cache` and delete all files with in chache folder

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to make any changes at the Database level using queries after editing the secure url in admin panel?

Comment: @Benjamin you dont have to make changes in database once you made chnages in admin panel

Answer (score 4):

After the change from dedicated IP address to domain you need to set **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url** in **core_config_data** table

you can find this using sql query

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%base_url%'
```

and change value from ip address to domain name

i.e.

http://10.16.16.109/project/ to  http://www.example.com/

And make sure file permissions are currect

Answer (score 0):

"Path"
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url

when value is changing to domain name not working properly.page shows 404 Error.Giving IP adress working fine.
I cleared cache.